# Change the color of selected menu item using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight currently opening page using css styles.here is my html code

```html
<ul class="nav" id="nav">
  <li id="home">
    <a href="home.html" data-id="home" target="ifrm">Home</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="item1.html" target="ifrm">item1</a></li>
     <li><a href="item2.html" target="ifrm">item2</a></li>
     <li><a href="item3.html" target="ifrm">item3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="skill"><a href="skill.html" data-id="skill" target="ifrm">Skill</a></li>
  <li id="research"><a href="research.html" data-id="research"    target="ifrm">Research</a></li>
  <li id="link"><a href="link.html" data-id="link" target="ifrm">Link</a></li>
</ul>
<iframe name="ifrm"></iframe>
```

It should be only change the font and background color of menu list ,witch page is loading in the iframe.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: When I click in a menu item, the page will be load in to the iframe.so I want to highlight (changing menu item's font color and background color) the menu item of which I was clicked.If I select another menu item that one should be highlight not previous one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
   $('li a').click(function(){
     $('li a').each(function(a){
       $( this ).removeClass('selectedclass')
     });
     $( this ).addClass('selectedclass');
   });
  
  $('ul a').click(function(){
     $('ul a').each(function(a){
      $( this ).removeClass('selectedclass')
     });
     $( this ).addClass('selectedclass');
   });
});
```

```css
li a.selectedclass
{
  color:red;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav" id="nav">
          <li id="home"><a href="home.html" data-id="home" target="ifrm">Home</a>
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="item1.html" target="ifrm">item1</a></li>
      <li ><a href="item2.html" target="ifrm">item2</a></li>
      <li ><a href="item3.html" target="ifrm">item3</a></li>

    </ul>
    
    </li>
          <li id="skill"><a href="skill.html" data-id="skill" target="ifrm">Skill</a></li>
          <li id="research"><a href="research.html" data-id="research"    target="ifrm">Research</a></li>
          <li id="link"><a href="link.html" data-id="link" target="ifrm">Link</a></li>
        </ul>

<iframe name="ifrm"></iframe>
```

You need to define first a class that has required styles and then click of anchor tag remove this class from all the class and then add it to the clicked anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks.that's what I wanted to do really.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your file

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("a").click(function(){
        $("a").css("color","BLUE"); // change this color to default one
        $( this ).css( "color", "RED" ); 
    });
</script>
```